# Google+ stop sharing in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-plus, social-networking

I integrated Google+ sharing in my app. It works find few days ago but from last 3-4 days, it stops sharing means it does not show any prefilltext or image,etc. just shows blank share.

**My code is as follow:**

```
<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
[shareBuilder setTitle:@"Share" description:@"sharing" thumbnailURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9p3n1vJmZ1rexr16o1_400.jpg"]];
[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"rest=1234567"];
[shareBuilder open];
```

**I don't know why this happen? Help me to solve this.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 - (void)shareOnGooglePlus:(NSDictionary *)content
        {
            GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
            signIn.clientID = (NSString *) TempGoogleClientID;

            signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,GooglePlusScopeProfile,GooglePlusScopeEmail,GooglePlusScopeMe,nil];
            signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = TRUE;
            //[signIn authenticate];
            id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

            [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;

            [shareBuilder setURLToShare:content[URLKey]];
            [shareBuilder setPrefillText:content[FeedTitleKey]];

        [shareBuilder open];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! Let me try.

Comment: Give ur scopes there.those are constants.NSString *const GooglePlusScopeMe = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" ;
NSString *const GooglePlusScopeProfile = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
NSString *const GooglePlusScopeEmail = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

Comment: and kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ??

Comment: That from "GTLPlusConstants.h" file.Google plus constants

Comment: its worked for me. check ur pre settings for google like ur google console,google id,add url types to ur project etc

Comment: It told me that user must sign-in before using native sharing box. –